# What is the recommended way to include a global module with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working on a large application using Webpack that includes a global `settings.js` file that all other modules need access to. Rather than add an `import settings from '../path/to/settings';` to the top of all modules, I'm hoping there is a more succinct way to make it available to all modules by default.

Suggestions for adding a module globally available to all others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered I was already doing this with `webpack.ProvidePlugin`. Extended it to include my settings file:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: [
            'src',
            'node_modules'
        ],
        extensions: ['', '.json', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            settings: 'settings'
        })
    ]
};
```

My `settings.js` file is inside of `src`, which is already being accesed via the `resolve` Webpack config item.